# Wi-Fi connected but there is no internet access

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I have a **Samsung Galaxy S Advance (Android upgraded to 4.1.2 Jelly Bean)** which I got only one month before. Wi-Fi was initially working great, but now it doesn't have any internet connection even if Wi-Fi gets connected.

The Wi-Fi gets connected to my laptop, my PC and my father's Android mobile phone, but not on my device. What might be the reason?

Comment: If you go to *Settings→WiFi*, is your AP listed as "connected" – or does it show something different, like `trying to obtain IP address`? The settings of your AP might have gotten messed up. If that's the case, long-tap the AP entry in that list, chose "remove". Switch WiFi off and on again, let it scan for available networks, and try re-adding yours. If there are any errors displayed, please [edit] your question and include the details.

Answer (score 3):

You can try changing your wifi network settings from DHCP to Static and a little tweaking of DNS server addresses should work. refer this [link](http://www.techsiddhi.com/2014/05/how-to-resolve-connected-to-wifi-but-no.html) for complete solution.

Under advance settings Change IP Settings from DHCP to Static

IP Address : Most probably your Gateway address will be 192.168.1.1 change your IP Address my changing last digit in this address use any value preferably between 2 to 20.

Change DNS1 to 8.8.8.8

Change DNS2 to 8.8.4.4

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (please [edit] your question and do so). Otherwise your question ceases to be helpful in case the link dies.

Comment: I don't know why, but DHCP wouldn't work. After factory resetting the phone and the router, my phone was the only device that wouldn't connect to the internet.

I checked the IP address and gateway and it had values that made no sense. So I changed the binding method from DHCP to static and now I can access the internet again :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to wifi settings. click on the access point, remove the password, and input the password again.

If still doesn't work then follow the steps:

1. Go to your dialer and type `*#*#4636#*#*` (`*#*#info#*#*`)
2. click on wifi-info > wifi-api
3. then disconnect > disableNetwork -> enableNetwork

and you are good to go

Comment: soory please i didnt got you can u tell me again stepwise cause i have removed the password and put the password again but its still not working.... please tell me each and every step please

Comment: go to your dialer pad and then follow the steps written above

Answer (score 2):

My father's Galaxy S Advance suddenly lost it's WiFi connectivity one day. I tried the code `*#*#4636#*#*` and tried to update the WiFi connection by disabling and enabling it, but that didn't work for me.

Then I came across [this blog post](http://anxiousnut.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/a-weird-android-obtaining-ip-address-wifi-issue-workaround/) which worked:

1. Turn off WiFi
2. Turn on the static IP option (you can find this in "Advanced Settings")
3. Turn on WiFi
4. Turn off the static IP option - make sure to tap the screen to get the "save" option for this.
5. Your device should establish a connection

Answer (score 1):

My tablet does this too, it shows perfect WiFi connection but apps don't connect. I read in another forum that the date/time gets reset somehow, nobody can figure out how or why and Samsung is oblivious, but...

Go in and set your date/time to the correct one and voila, it connects! It will reset again eventually and you'll have to go in and do it again but it works.

I was shocked to see when I read that, that the setting was in fact at January 2012, but I did it and it worked. I also read about seeing the severity from the WPA to A..something, (AEP?) I'm not really familiar with security settings, and I couldn't find where to do it, but many people said that it corrected the problem for them. Lastly, the KIES has also worked for some, I guess turning it on with WiFi makes it connect. I have only tried the date/time setting, but they may all be connected somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem with my GS2. I tried all the steps defined here and in other blogs... but it didn't work with my problem.

Then,

**I connected my phone to another router, then reconnected it to my own router... it worked perfectly.**

Answer (score -1):

I also experienced same problem with my Samsung Advance for couple of days.

I rebooted my phone, reset the factory settings, removed the battery/SIM, turned ON/OFF the static IP option, but it did not work.

Last thing I did was: I clicked the KIES AIR, and clicked WI-FI. After a few moments, I got a signal to our company Wi-Fi. Try this option, and hope it will work out.

Answer (score -2):

Go into your WiFi list and forget all of your remembered networks, then reconfigure them.

Comment: 1) Why all, if only one has problems? 2) Reconfigure *them* would require to have them all in reach.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem, after a lot of struggle finally found out the issue was with the security type, changed the router`s security type from wpa2 to wep128 bits, and it worked fine :)

Comment: Wep is unsafe. It can easily be broken in a few minutes, and generally shouldn't be used anymore. It has about the same security as hiding the SSID, or using MAC address restrictions.

Answer (score -3):

try to update your cellphone date and time... ^_^

Comment: While this indeed might be the culprit, would you mind to [edit] your answer, elaborate a little, and let the OP know why?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried your Wi-Fi on any other device? It could be possible that it is connecting as a remote hard drive.

Comment: Excuse me, but I've never heard that Android devices pretend to be a "WiFi harddrive". The WiFi AP obviously works for at least 3 other devices (as the OP describes in the question). The only point left is to try the *Galaxy S* on a different AP, correct. But that has nothing to do with "remote harddrives".

Comment: sometimes you can have a router hooked up as a remote data server, with wireless conectivity, but no inernet

Comment: While that might be, how then would you explain the other mentioned devices being able to connect without issues?